# How do I enable pagination on a taxonomy term page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term page displaying node teasers. I would like to know how I can enable pagination on it?

Thanks

Comment: The default taxonomy page already has a pager - any reason you can't use that one?

Comment: I can't locate it, it's not appearing for some strange reason!

Answer (score 3):

There is a default view for that. If you have installed [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module, you can just enable the view named 'Taxonomy Term', which is disabled by default.

Then you can adjust the pager settings in the view configuration interface.

Comment: Do I have any hope of including a page that doesn't involve the views taxonomy page?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you want to mean.